# Regexp finding substring with conditions

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to write regexp to find a number with a minus sign in the string.

1. This number has a minus(-) sign on begin or on the end number.
2. This substring can start or/and end with space or start or end the string.
3. Another string can contain this substring, but without space and this string need to exclude

**the regexp should match these strings**

```
abc ghhkjl -123
123- gfdhs kljf
fdsg -123 fdjol
jklp 123- ljfds
-123
123-
```

**the regexp shouldn't match these strings**

```
abc ghhkjl-123
123-gfdhs kljf
fdsg -123fdjol
jklp123- ljfds
```

My regexp I did

```
(?:^|\W|\w+\s)\d+(?:$|\W|\s\w+)
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to force being surrounded by whitespace, start or end.

```
(?<!\S)(?:\d+-|-\d+)(?!\S)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DTjtGg/1)

The upper `\S` matches a character, that is not a whitespace (negation of `\s`).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you want to find a single number you could repeat matching word characters and horizontal whitespace chars on the left and on the right of the number which has a minus sign either on the left or right:

```
^(?:\h*\w+\h+)*(\d+-|-\d+)(?:\h+\w+\h*)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace chars at the begin
  - `\w+\h+` Match 1+ word chars followed by 1+ horizontal whitspace chars
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(\d+-|-\d+)` Capture group 1, the number with the minus sign
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\h+\w+` Match 1+ horizontal whitspace chars and 1+ word chars
  - `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitspace chars at the end
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/04HzAk/1)

Comment: Neat idea to match the full string!